# ErpNext creating sales invoice via api throws an error object has no attribute 'payment_terms'

Tags: erpnext

Am using erpnext api to create sales invoice with rest api with javascript axios and the data been posted is

```
            const salesData = {
                customer: 'Customer Name',
                company: 'Company Name',
                items: saleItems.map((el) => ({
                    item_code: el.code, 
                    qty: el.qty,
                    rate: el.price,
                })

                ),
                posting_date: '2023-10-03',
                due_date: '2023-12-10',
                payment_terms: 'Net 30 Days' // Include the payment terms here
            };
```

Am posting data via axios with

```
   axios({
          url:'https://erpnextapi.../resource/Sales Invoice',
          data:salesData, 
          { headers: ...authHeaders })
   .then((res)=>{...}, err=>{...})
```

The above always throws an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'payment_terms'
```

What could be wrong since the payment terms Net 30 days already exists.
What am i missing

Answer (score 0):

I resolved changing the:
customer: 'Customer Name',
by
customer: 'Customer ID',